# $\Vert f \Vert^{2}$, where $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable with $f(0)=0$. Prove that $$\Vert f \Vert^{2} = \int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^{2}dx$$

Here $\Vert f \Vert$ is given by $\sup\{|f(t)|: t \in [0,1]\}$.

I see how to prove that $(\int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^{2}dx)^{1/2}$ is an upper bound for $f(t)$, where $t \in [0,1]$, from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711337/upper-bound-for-vert-f-vert2-where-f-0-1-to-mathbbr-continuousl).

However, I am not sure how to prove this is the *least* upper bound.

Comment: How about $f(x)=\sin{2n\pi x}$ with large $\alpha$? The LHS is $1$ but the RHS is (I think) 2n^2\pi^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Take $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x(1-x)$. Then $\|f\|=\frac14$, but$$\int_0^1(f'(x))^2\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1(1-2x)^2\,\mathrm dx=\frac13.$$